# How to reset indexes in array_diff result?

Tags: php

I have two arrays: `Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 )` and `Array ( [0] => 2 )`.

I want to get the value, which is not in second array. So I have used the `array_diff` function  but my result will get  `Array ( [1] => 3 )` 
 Actually this is the result. But a small problem here, its position is (key) `1`. I want the result in to a new array starts from 0th position, i.e., `Array ( [0] => 3 )`.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you explain why having the original keys in place causes a problem?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

you can use `array_values(array_diff($arr1, $arr2));` if order doesn't matter

Answer (score 22):

You should run `array_values()` on the result and this would give you a new array with indexes starting at 0.

This is a known shortcoming of `array_diff()`, check the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php).