# Delete all matching items in an array and shift index

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
$array = array("a", "b", 0, "c", 0);
```

How can I remove all elements with 0 and shift the index of the remaining elements?

I want the result to be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
array_diff($bal_units, array(0));
```

Comment: call ``array_values`` on the result to reset the index. as: ``array_values(array_diff($bal_units, array(0)))`` https://3v4l.org/f75rN

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3109098/how-to-reset-indexes-in-array-diff-result

Comment: `$array = array_filter($array)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove duplicate values from an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307650/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score -1):

```
//input

$array = array("a", "b", 0, "c", 0);

$array = array_diff($array, array(0));

if (($key = array_search(0, $array)) !== false) {

    array_splice($array, $key, 0);
}

print_r($array);
```

RESULT

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => b [2] => c )
```

Comment: But that is an exact copy of what the OP have already tried. And, as the OP said, it indeed doesn't work (index 2 is not element "c").

Comment: I made some code updates. It is currently working in accordance with the specifications.